# Struggling Returning indexes from array when characters match pattern

Tags: arrays, function, javascript

Im trying to return indexes from an array, when the characters in the array match search term regardless of the characters order in the array .

```
array = ['hell on here', '12345', '77788', 'how are you llo']

function charmatch(array,lookFor){
Indexarray = [];

for(I=0; I<array.length;I++){
If (lookFor.charAt(I) <= array.indexOf(I))
Indexarray[Indexarray.length] = I
```

}
return Indexarray;

```
}
document.write(charmatch(array,"hello") )
```

So this should return 0,3 in the array. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery the grep ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/ ) function may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function charmatch(arr, lookfor) {
    var result = [],
        split,
        found = false;

    // Iterate over every item in the array
    for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        found = false;
        // Create a new array of chars
        split = arr[i].split('');
        // Iterate over every character in 'lookfor'
        for (var j = 0; j<lookfor.length; j++) {
            found = false;
            // Iterate over every item in the split array of chars
            for (var k=0; k<split.length; k++) {
              // If the chars match, then we've found one, 
              // therefore exit the loop
              if (lookfor.charAt(j) === split[k]) {
                found = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            // char not found, therefor exit the loop
            if (!found) {
                break;
            }
            // Remove the first item (which is a char), thus
            // avoiding matching an already matched char
            split.shift();
        }
        // if 'found' is true by now, then it means all chars have been found
        if (found) {
            // Add the current index to the result array
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

charmatch(['hell on here', '12345', '77788', 'how are you llo'], 'hello');
```